# Switching to command line from x in fedora?

Tags: fedora, lxde

I know that in debian C+A+BCKSPACE shuts down X server and switches to command line. How should I achieve this in fedora 17, my default DE is lxde. When I press C+A+BCKSPACE it just logs me out.

Answer (score 2):

`setxkbmap -option terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp` will enable you to kill X with that keystroke (put it in `.xinitrc` or something for it to autorun).

However, killing your X server every time is not recommended. You should rather do a graceful shutdown.

A better way is using a [terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) or using one of the six [virtual terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) that are set up by default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>.
Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> will bring you back to X.